# using jQuery to select and edit nested values in this script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to access and change the elements of an object within a function using jQuery? For example, can I use a separate jQuery function to access line 33 of the JS on this JSfiddle and dynamically change the content of the chart title?

(I've tried replacing `text: 'Activity',` with a reference to an object property such as `text: myObj.title,` with no luck)

```js
$(function () {

    // Uncomment to style it like Apple Watch
    /*
    if (!Highcharts.theme) {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: 'black'
            },
            colors: ['#F62366', '#9DFF02', '#0CCDD6'],
            title: {
                style: {
                    color: 'silver'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                style: {
                    color: 'silver'
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // */

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            marginTop: 50
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Activity',
            style: {
                fontSize: '24px'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            },
            pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
            positioner: function (labelWidth) {
                return {
                    x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                    y: 180
                };
            }
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            background: [{ // Track for Move
                outerRadius: '112%',
                innerRadius: '88%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }, { // Track for Exercise
                outerRadius: '87%',
                innerRadius: '63%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }, { // Track for Stand
                outerRadius: '62%',
                innerRadius: '38%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickPositions: []
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                borderWidth: '34px',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                linecap: 'round',
                stickyTracking: false
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Move',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '100%',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                y: 80
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Exercise',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                radius: '75%',
                innerRadius: '75%',
                y: 65
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Stand',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                radius: '50%',
                innerRadius: '50%',
                y: 50
            }]
        }]
    },

    /**
     * In the chart load callback, add icons on top of the circular shapes
     */
    function callback() {

        // Move icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 26)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Exercise icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8, 'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 61)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Stand icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', 0, 8, 'L', 0, -8, 'M', -8, 0, 'L', 0, -8, 8, 0])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 96)
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a separate object for providing options in .chart method (second param). You can set the required value in option.title.text before the chart method executes. No change will be reflected if you change the value after method execute.

But if you want to change the value after the chart has been created then you will have to refer documentation of the Highcharts plugin.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, the script is self-executing anonymous function, you can't access anything inside it because it'll be out of scope. The scope within that function can only be accessed by other members inside it.

The only way to access something internally is to attache that value or method to the `window` object from within. This is essentially the "global" scope in Javascript.

```
window.whatever = 'something';
```

Then, you'll be able to access it from another script.

```
console.log(window.whatever);
```